# How to get corresponding file icon in Android?

Tags: android

Every file type associated with its specific **icon**.

Now if i am choosing **somefilename.xxx** then how i could be able to choose the icon associated with ***.xxx** rather than the default icon for unknown file.

**Original Question**

How can I get `.txt` or `.doc` or `.png` file icon? For example now I am choosing `filename.pdf`, how to get `filename.pdf` icon?
For example

```
File f = new File("filename.pdf");
```

My File name is `filename.pdf`. How to get this file icon (Adobereader Icon).

Comment: What are you trying for? Its not clear.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're close enough to getting the question across, but I don't understand it. Please try to re-state it.

Comment: wait. i modify this question.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete.

Comment: What's not clear???  How to get an icon for corresponding file type? This question is clear as day, brilliant in its clear presentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing i would like to say **any file do not contains it icon with them in general** say if you **don't have office** installed **you won't get doc icon or powerpoint icon**.

so its system work to associate icon to specific file type so Go this way

To achieve your goal its highly recommended to include all icons that you are expected to use 
say if You choose **some.png** check for extention and associate the **png.ico** to this file icon

doing this way you will have to associate with every type of files.

**Edit 1:**

you can easily find out the icons on web add to it into your drawable folder's now for every file name extract the extension and set the icon according to the extension 
this way you can achieve your goal

**Edit 2 :**

To achieve your goal do the following :

1. add all icon files to your res\drawable folder for easyness set all
   icon file name as its extension Say use **doc.png** for **doc
   extension** `for easyness`
2. Now map all file extension to your icon file say check for file
   extension and then do something like following:

> String ext = "Something";

```
switch(ext)    
{    
case "doc":    
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.doc);    
    break;     
case "exe":    
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.exe);
    break;
default :
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.default);    
}
```

Comment: I am using custom ListView to list out all the files from SD card. My First column is File ICon, Second Column is File Name. I am successfully viewed all file name. But each file has different extension. How to get this system file icon based on the extension.

Comment: Yes. Your answer is correct. But how to achieve goal. Because there are lot of extensions. How to set icons to types of files. Guide me.

Answer (score 6):

Try Using  [PackageManager.queryIntentActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29):

```
final Intent innt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
innt.setData(fileUri);
innt.setType("application/pdf");

final List<ResolveInfo> matches = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(innt, 0);
for (ResolveInfo match : matches) {
    final Drawable icon = match.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
    final CharSequence label = match.loadLabel(getPackageManager());
}
```

Comment: I am using custom `ListView` to list out all the files from SD card. My First column is File ICon, Second Column is File Name. I am successfully viewed all file name. But each file has different extension. How to get this system file icon based on the extension.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what OP said.He is trying to get icon of file not Android Application.

Comment: @user1474868 : What you are getting in label?

Comment: @imrankhan My First Column is image. Second column i get the FileName in the label (TextView).

Comment: @user1474868 : i think this is different issue can u post it plz as new question with relevant code .if my answer help u then mark it as answer.Thanks

Comment: @user1474868 : post it i will try to help u as much as possible in solving issue. thanks !!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that takes in a path, and by the file extension in its name, corresponds to the drawable.

```
fun getFileTypeIcon(path: String): Int {
    val file = File(path)
    val ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.name)
    Log.i("ImagesExt", "$path ----> $ext")
    return when (".$ext") {
        ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".bmp" -> R.drawable.image
        ".mp3", ".wav", ".ogg", "midi" -> R.drawable.audio
        ".mp4", ".rmvb", ".avi", ".flv", ".3gp" -> R.drawable.video
        ".jsp", ".html", ".htm", ".js", ".php" -> R.drawable.web
        ".txt", ".c", ".cpp", ".xml", ".py", ".json", ".log" -> R.drawable.file
        ".xls", ".xlsx" -> R.drawable.file
        ".doc", ".docx" -> R.drawable.file
        ".ppt", ".pptx" -> R.drawable.file
        ".pdf" -> R.drawable.pdf
        ".jar", ".zip", ".rar", ".gz" -> R.drawable.zip
        ".apk" -> R.drawable.apk
        else -> R.drawable.file
    }
}
```