# Default System Icons for File Types (Android)

Tags: android

**Is there an API that will return an icon for a given file extension?**

I need to display a file listing within a sub-view. (These are files "attached" to a record, so simply embedding a file explorer and dumping a directory will not suffice).

I've noticed that the built-in File Manager (Asus) and 3rd party Root Explorer both appear to be displaying the same icon's for types based on their "grouping" (text, images, ...).

For example, all text-files (.txt, .doc) have the same icon, and all image-files (.jpg, .png, ...) have the same icon (the exception to this is ES File Explorer, which has a specific icon for .txt and .doc files).

I've also observed that they each have their own set of icons (the text and image icon's in File Explorer are different that Root Explorer's).

So it appears that the common/best practice in Android is to display files by their content, not the the associated program that opens it (even if I specify a default app to open a certain file type, the icon doesn't appear to change).

**To avoid wheel re-invention, I would like to simply leverage an OS provided API that would return an icon when provided a file extension?**

Such an API method would provide consistency for any other app that needs to do this (by having uniform icons), and also result in future proofed code, as in the case of the "density profiles" being abandoned at some point (med, lg, xl, xxl, xxxl, ...).  I suppose it would need to return an icon formatted for the current screen density as well.

**NOTE:** I'd rather not refer to icons directly (ie, `android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"`) in case the paths to them ever break, but if that is the only way to achieve this then so be it (maybe I'll have to write a wrapper to abstract away).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an API that will return an icon for a given file extension?

Not directly, as Android does not deal with file extensions.

You are welcome to:

- Use `MimeTypeMap` to try to derive a MIME type for a file extension
- Craft an `Intent` that you would use for content with that MIME type
- Use `PackageManager` and `resolveActivity()` or `queryIntentActivities()` to find out what activity (or activities) would handle this `Intent`
- Use the resulting information, along with `PackageManager` to get the icon associated with the activity

IOW, you do what home screen launchers do, except that you would not be using a `LAUNCHER` `Intent`.

Comment: I was going to ask if it was possible with MIME types while first typing my question, but when I looked at all the MIME types here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types I realized they were not grouped how I thought (there is a specific MIME type for each file extension, not one for all picture types - gif and jpeg have their own MIME types... I guess I can use **`images/*`** - oh duh I forgot about the wildcards). Thanks!

Comment: **ρяσѕρєя K** 's answer deals with the PackageManager option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238519/how-to-get-corresponding-file-icon-in-android

Comment: I'm looking to display an simple/basic icon associated to a file type that will be consistent across devices. Displaying an application icon that is arbitrarily associated to a file type will not be.  Also, because application icons are subject to change when that application updates, another  level of inconsistency results.

Comment: @SamusArin: "I'm looking to display an simple/basic icon associated to a file type that will be consistent across devices" -- there is nothing in Android for that. "Displaying an application icon that is arbitrarily associated to a file type will not be consistent across devices" -- I would expect that users want to know *what app of theirs* will handle the content, rather than some random icon that they may not recognize. Few, if any, of your users will be comparing the results of your app between devices.

Comment: What about the case when there are multiple available apps (ie, a default app hasn't yet been chosen)? Then I'm back to needing a generic icon to display until a default app is chosen, or use an arbitrary app icon from the matching result set returned from the **`PackageManager`**.

Comment: @SamusArin: Correct. There is very little that you can do about that.

Comment: Well, I like the idea of showing an activity icon now, and the code seems simple enough that the overhead is negligible. Since I need to setup my icons "manually" anyway, I'll start with that, but will add this other feature in if I can get it cleared. It only makes sense b/c that user selected the default app to begin with, so why not show them that apps icon from there on out. Thanks CommonsWare.